# REST API design: complex query with GET

Tags: json, api, rest, post, get

I am designing a REST call that should deliver information for a location (lat/lon) and consider the user context/configuration.

As the number of user properties is high and nested, I am not sure, what is the correct way to design a new query (GET vs POST). Currently we use a POST request for simplicity - the query payload could look like this, but is custom and very different for each user. It also includes an array of multiple configuration items. Currently the request looks like this:

POST http://api.something.com/locationInformation

```
{
  "location": {
    "accuracy": 30,
    "coordinates": [
      16.34879820048809,
      48.230067741347334
    ],
    "provider": "network",
    "timestamp": "2016-01-06T12:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "userConfiguration": [
    {
      "id": "asdfasdfasdfs09898sdf",
      "values": [
        "false"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "iojkljio230909sdjklsdf",
      "values": [
        "99jkjiouio89",
        "sdfilkjöjfoi093s09sdf"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So my question is: is it in such a case ok to "abuse" a POST request in order to query information?

Is there an elegant way to pass such data using a GET request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434872/rest-api-design-complex-query-with-get

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can pass this data using a GET request by passing it to a request header.
use the    `header()` method.Initialize a String variable say    `String data=//your json;` and pass it to the header as follows    `header("data",data)` in your client while building the request.

Comment: well, technically I could... but that does not seem bet practice to me!?

Comment: It is certainly not !! But i see developers do it if they need to.